# Array operation in Python

Tags: python, arrays, cycle

How do I do the following in Python:

```
array_1 = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, ....]
array_2 = [y1, y2, y3]

array_3 = [(x1-y1), (x2-y2), (x3-y3), (x4-y1), (x5-y2), (x6-y3)]
```

The number of elements in `array_2` is always less than the number of elements in `array_1`.

`array_1` and `array_2` have an arbitrary number of elements.

`[num of elements in array_1]` mod `[number of elements in array_2]` = 0

Comment: Besides having spaces in your identifiers, what's wrong with what you already have?

Comment: @Wobbly: Presumably this is just an example and the OP has much larger lists than these.

Comment: Yes the real arrays are much larger. This is just a simple example.

Comment: Can array_2 ever be bigger than array_1?

Comment: the number of elements in array_2 is always less than the number of elements in array_1

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to acheive rather than giving us a single example?

Comment: @2one: It'd be great if you edited your question to add clarifications. :-) I added your second comment to the question itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Itertools has loads of tools to accommodate your problem

Understanding your problem

1. One of the array is shorter than the other
2. The Shorter array should be [cycled](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) until the longer array is exhausted
3. [Create a pair](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) of the longer array and the cycled shorter array
4. [Subtract the elements within the pair](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)

So here is the implementation

```
>>> arr1 = range(1,10)
>>> arr2 = range(20,23)
>>> from operator import sub
>>> from itertools import izip, cycle, starmap
>>> list(starmap(sub, izip(arr1, cycle(arr2))))
[-19, -19, -19, -16, -16, -16, -13, -13, -13]
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No reason, a bad habit. Corrected :-)

Answer (score 10):

```
from itertools import izip, cycle

array_3 = [a - b for a, b in izip(array_1, cycle(array_2))]
```

which would accomodate arbitrary sizes for array_2.

Here [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) combines elements from both lists into pairs, and the [`itertools.cycle()` utility](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) will re-use the second list over and over again to provide something to pair with.

If you don't need a list as output, only need to iterate over the result, you could use [`itertools.imap()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) and [`operator.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.sub) too:

```
from itertools import imap, cycle
import operator

for result in imap(operator.sub, array_1, cycle(array_2)):
    # do something with the result
```

For large input lists, this saves you having to store the intermediary results in yet another list.

Comment: -1, you're passing a single tuple to `operator.sub` which expects 2 arguments :)

Comment: @mgilson: minor detail, easily fixed. :-) I could have used starmap too, but the output needs to be a list.

Comment: -1 revoked :) -- I toyed around with `map(sub,array1,cycle(array2))`, but that's bad news also -- On python2.x it would go forever since `map` took the longer of the two sequences.

Comment: @mgilson: this is *one* area where `izip` is the better idea. :-P

Comment: Yeah, I had done it with `zip` -- I was perusing the `itertools` docs when you posted your solution.  I can never keep `cycle` and `repeat` straight in my head :) -- (mostly because I can't remember the name of `cycle`)

Comment: Rather `starmap` and `izip`, you could use `imap`, which does not require pre-zipping: `for result in imap(operator.sub, array_1, cycle(array_2)):`

Comment: @Robᵩ: Ah, I didn't consider `imap()` because `map()` doesn't stop with the shortest input iterable. Updated.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `operator.sub` with `map`:

```
array_3 = map(operator.sub,array_1,array_2+array_2)
```

Or, you could do it with `zip`:

```
array_3 = [x-y for x,y in zip(array_1,array2+array2)]
```

And you can get rid of the silly concatenation of array2 with itself using [itertools.cycle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```
array_3 = [x-y for x,y in zip(array_1,cycle(array_2))]
```